# Swift - MKPointAnnotation custom pin image

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 10 beta 3 and I need to use a custom image for my pins on the map. I need to avoid the red annotation pins and use some custom logos that I made for this. I tried all the solutions found on stack but nothing helped me. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1)
        let locationANTOMI:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.4509339, 9.1713609)
        let locationANTOTO:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.06666, 7.68826)
        //let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        //map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let annotationANTOMI = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotationANTOMI.coordinate = locationANTOMI
        annotationANTOMI.title = "ANTONIOLI MILANO"

        map.addAnnotation(annotationANTOMI)

        let annotationANTOTO = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotationANTOTO.coordinate = locationANTOTO
        annotationANTOTO.title = "ANTONIOLI TORINO"
        map.addAnnotation(annotationANTOTO)
    }
}
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I usually do it is to create a new swift file that will be your custom annotation which inherits from MKAnnoatation. Example below

```
import MapKit

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var image: UIImage? = nil

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        //self.image
        super.init()
    }
}
```

You will need to initialise your annotation where the CLCoordinate is compulsory. Then set the image property with your custom image. `MyAnnotation.image = "myImage.png". You will then need to add your annotation to your map view`mapView.addAnnotations(MyAnnotation).
I also implement the method below from the MKMapViewDelegate (Make sure your inherit this in your class). This is so that the user can tap on the annotation and receive information about it. Hope this helps.

In your view controller:

```
let marker = MyAnnotation(title: "title" as! String, subtitle: "subtitle" as! String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
marker.image = UIImage("my image.png")
self.mapView.addAnnotations(marker)

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation {
        let identifier = "identifier"
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.image = annotation.image //add this
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure) as UIView
        return annotationView
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I did all you said but when I declare locationANTOTO.image = "image.png", this error pops "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?"

Comment: You will need to cast your image to a UIIamge. locationANTOTO.image = UIImage("image.png")

Comment: I mean initialise rather than cast. Make sure image.png is added to your project

Comment: Where should I put my image? in which folder?

Comment: locationANTOTO.image = UIImage(named: "antonioli.png") , I put my logo into main folder but still red pin pops..

Comment: Have you initialised your custom annotation object?

Comment: let locationANTOTO:Annotation = Annotation(title: "Antonioli Torino",subtitle: "",coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.06666, 7.68826)) this is how I initialised it

Comment: Yeah that looks fine

Comment: Try setting your annotation image withiin func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?

Comment: not working. after the declaration I have: locationLVR.image = UIImage(named: "antonioli.png") map.addAnnotation(locationLVR)

Comment: the mapView on the viewController ?

Comment: error on all rows: Use of unresolved identifier 'annotationView'

Comment: put let in front of it when you declare annotationView. Or have annotationView as a class property

Comment: last error, I'm so noob lmao : Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'MKAnnotationView'

Comment: Take out the the question marks on annotationView when calling methods on it. That’s only is it is set as a call property as nil

Comment: Value of type '(MKMapView, MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?' has no member 'addAnnotations' on mapView.addAnnotations(marker)